# Make Microsoft Word Display Individual Page Word Count

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I don't know if this is possible to do - I haven't found any way of doing so yet (although someone mentioned it *might* be possible using a registery hack).

I work on Microsoft Word pretty much all day every day, and word count is very important. Now, at the bottom-left-hand-corner there is, of course, the word count of the entire document - my question...

Is it possible to display the word count of the current page, automatically?

I know you can highlight text, etc - but ideally, I'd love to find a way it could display automatically. Thanks in advance!

(I'm using Office 2016 - installed using the deployment tool - on a Windows 10 Pro PC)

Comment: Word help says "Count the number of words in a part of a document

To count the number of words in only part of your document, select the text you want to count, and then on the Review tab, click Word Count." I don't think you can do what you want to do without selecting the text first...

Comment: As text is normally continously floating between pages as you type on any page, this would be consuming significant computing power, so I doubt it is available in any way (unless you program it yourself in VB).

Comment: Gotcha, thinking about it, it would likely make word extremelly lag-prone and unresponsive

Comment: You could use this example for an ad-hoc word count message box https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-words-property-word

Comment: There's also some VBA here which might help, but assumes you're using section breaks http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-21723.html

Comment: Appreciate your help - both options look as though they could be some type of compromise as to what I'm looking for, so will give them a go!